# Inject AJAX MooTools response

Tags: php, ajax, mootools

I have a form where the user will input a text and when he submits the form, the text I want must be injected, I think, or simply attached to the page like AJAX comments, but my problem is that I can get the message on the page.

I have the code working tested (I have alert the message and other stuff).

Here's my code:

```
en4.questionanswer = {

 postAnswer : function() {
   var mess = $('a_mess');
   var user_id = $('q_user_id');
   var question_id = $('question_id');
   //check if value is blank

   //post Question
   var request = new Request.JSON({
     'method' : 'post',
     'url' :  en4.core.baseUrl + 'question/postans',
     'data' : {
       'mess' : mess.value,            
       'question_id' : question_id.value                                   
     },
     'onComplete':function(responseObject) {
        if( typeof(responseObject)!="object") {
          //alert('ERR');
        }
        else {                                
          if (responseObject.result == "success") {                        
            mess.value=''; //clear text after submiting
            // en4.questionanswer.start("1");
            alert(responseObject.answer);
          }
          else {                        
            alert(responseObject.message);
          }            
        }
      }
    });
    request.send();
  }
});
```

In the PHP part I have:

```
echo json_encode(array("result" => "success",
                       "message" => "Post message successful!",
                       "answer" => $content));
```

Comment: Does Firebug or some other tool give bugs? Furthermore, `mess.value='';` should be written as `mess.erase('value');`. Maybe that might be part of the problem? Otherwise, try http://jsfiddle.net so we can debug your script better.

Comment: Did you mean to say your problem is "..._can't_ get the message on the page"? Your javascript does not have any code trying to place the response into the page. Can you give us more details so we know how you would like to interact with the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

If responseObject.answer is the answer you are trying to place in the page this will get you started.

replace the alert(responseObject.answer) in the onComplete function with:

```
new Element('div': {
    html: responseObject.answer,
    class: 'optionalClassName'
}).inject($(document.body));
```

Replace $(document.body) with any selector you would like example:

```
$('comments')
```

or

```
$$('#comments .someOther > .selector')
```

The information provided in your post was very limited so if I missed the mark I apologize, just trying to point you in the right direction.